# Неверная кодировка sitemap.xml

Tags: seo, sitemap, яндекс-вебмастер

При загрузке на Яндекс.вебмастер карты сайта выходит ошибка:

> Неверная кодировка.

Проверял карту сайта и в валидаторе, и на других сервисах, работает правильно. В Google вебмастер на карту не ругается. Принимает и индексирует, а Яндекс.вебмастер - нет. В чем может быть проблема?
[Ссылка на карту сайта](http://md.com.kz/sitemap.xml)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот такой тег

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

Т.е. пропишите его вместо того `urlset`, который у вас.